# Solve $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}$

Tags: limits, radicals

I am having great problems in solving this:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}$$

I am trying to solve this for hours, no solution in sight. I tried so many ways on my paper here, which all lead to nonsense or to nowhere. I concluded that I have to use the third binomial formula here, so my next step would be:

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$ so

$$a-b=\frac{a^3-b^3}{a^2+ab+b^2}$$

I tried expanding it as well, which led to absolutely nothing. These are my writings to this:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}=\frac{n+\sqrt{n}-n}{(n+\sqrt{n})^{2/3}+(n+\sqrt{n})^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}\leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n^{2/3}+n^{1/3}n^{1/3}+n^{2/3}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3n^{2/3}}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: That is the clearest explanation I got, I can really understand everything there - which I can seldom say because my knowledge of maths is very limited (for now). I have chosen yours as the best, thank you! Keep your service up!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach where we do not use of the identity $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2).$$

We have that
$$0< \sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\frac{
\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}-1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[6]{n}}\cdot \frac{1}{3}.$$
where we used the [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) 
$$(1+x)^r\leq 1+rx$$
with $r=1/3\in(0,1)$ and $x=1/\sqrt{n}$.

Can you take it from here?

P.S. By using this approach we are also able to find
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left((n+\sqrt{n})^r-n^r\right)$$
for any $r<1/2$. Note that if we replace $\sqrt[3]{\ }$ with say $\sqrt[5]{\ }$ then the "algebraic way" could be very annoying!

Comment: That looks really plausible and I could basically conclude that it converges to 0 with your term. But I have no Idea how I could rewrite the term in your manner, so that would sadly not help me in other tasks :(.... How did you rewrite it like that, by using which rules?

Comment: Do you agree that $\sqrt[3]{n}\cdot (
\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}-1)=\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}$? Recall that $\sqrt[3]{a}\sqrt[3]{b}=\sqrt[3]{ab}$.

Comment: I must have been blind..... Got that! I still have to admit that I don't get the denominator.

Comment: $\sqrt{n}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=1$...

Comment: It is much better now, but still really tough for me to understand. Would it be another questions I would have great problems with it, no doubt. I started studying 2 months ago, so eventually I will fully understand that as well. Thanks, Sir!

Answer (score 3):

By first order binomial expansion $(1+x)^r=1+rx + o(x)$, we have

$$\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt[3]{n}\, \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt n}\right)^\frac13=\sqrt[3]{n}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{3\sqrt n}+o\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt n}\right)=\sqrt[3]{n}+\frac{1}{3n^\frac16}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^\frac16}\right)$$

therefore

$$\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt{n}}-\sqrt[3]{n}=\frac{1}{3n^\frac16}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^\frac16}\right)$$

Comment: May I ask why $(1+x)^r=1+rx+o(x)$ when $r$ is fractional?

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall Yes of course! By binomial theorem $(1+x)^r=1+rx+r(r-1)^x^2+...=1+rx+o(x). Refer also to [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The binomial theorem for fractional exponent looks mysterious to me.

Comment: @WilliamMcGonagall It can be derived by Taylor's expansion, are you aware about it?

Comment: Yes, but I wasn't familiar with the order of growth of $\binom{r}{k}$ and so I didn't know what the radius of convergence of the series would be.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested,
\begin{align}
\sqrt[3]{n+\sqrt n} - \sqrt[3]{n} &= \frac{n+\sqrt n - n}{(n+\sqrt n)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{n(n+\sqrt n)} + n^{2/3}}\\
&= \frac{\sqrt n}{(n+\sqrt n)^{2/3}+\sqrt[3]{n(n+\sqrt n)} + n^{2/3}}.
\end{align}
The fastest growing term is evidently $n^{2/3}$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=x^{1/3}$.  By the mean value theorem there's a number $y\in (n, n+\sqrt n)$ such that
$$
f(n+\sqrt n) - f(n) = f'(y)(n+\sqrt n - n)= \frac{y^{-2/3}}{3}\sqrt n<n^{-2/3}\sqrt n=n^{-1/6}\to 0.
$$